# How to read this command to remove all blanks at the end of a line

Tags: regex, vim

I happened across this page full of super useful and rather cryptic vim tips at http://rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html.  I've tried a few of these and I understand what is happening enough to be able to parse it correctly in my head so that I can possibly recreate it later.  One I'm having a hard time getting my head wrapped around though are the following two commands to remove all spaces from the end of every line

```
:%s=  *$==                  : delete end of line blanks
:%s= \+$==                  : Same thing
```

I'm interpreting `%s` as string replacement on every line in the file, but after that I am getting lost in what looks like some gnarly variation of :s and regex.  I'm used to seeing and using :s/regex/replacement.  But the above is super confusing.

What do those above commands mean in english, step by step?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The regex delimiters don't have to be slashes, they can be other characters as well. This is handy if your search or replacement strings contain slashes. In this case I don't know why they use equal signs instead of slashes, but you can pretend that the equals are slashes:

```
:%s/  *$//     
:%s/ \+$//
```

Does that make sense? The first one searches for a space followed by zero or more spaces, and the second one searches for one or more spaces. Each one is anchored at the end of the line with `$`. And then the replacement string is empty, so the spaces are deleted.

I understand your confusion, actually. If you look at `:help :s` you have to scroll down a few pages before you find this note:

> #### *E146*
>
> Instead of the `'/'` which surrounds the pattern and replacement string, you
>   can use any other character, but not an alphanumeric character, `'\'`, `'"'` or
>   `'|'`.  This is useful if you want to include a `'/'` in the search pattern or
>   replacement string. Example:
>
> ```
> :s+/+//+
> ```

Comment: Thanks!  That explains it and is super helpful.  I had absolutely no clue you could use something besides / to delimit your regex replacement.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know `vim` syntax, but it looks to me like these are `sed`-style substitution operators. In `sed`, the `/` (in `s/REGEX/REPLACEMENT/`) can be uniformly replaced with any other single character. Here it appears to be `=`. So if you mentally replace `=` with `/`, you'll get

```
:%s/  *$//
:%s/ \+$//
```

which should make more sense to you.

Comment: If it were possible to accept both answers, I would.  thanks!